# Customize UIDatePicker.. how to change the background of each value in the date, hour and minute picker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to indicate working hours in the UIDatePicker. Therefore I need to set a background image under the hours between 8 AM to 5PM as an indication.

I have googled a lot but could not find a solution to this. Is it possible to customize the UIDatePicker to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it isn't. I have never seen an app do that, and the documentation doesn't say anything about it. If I was you, I would use a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells.